# How are Ciphers, MACs and Key exchange algorithms negotiated by OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, encryption, openssh

Looking at the man page for sshd_config I see the default list of algorithms for Ciphers, Key Exchange (KEX) and MACs.
In my set up, I have selected a subset of these algorithms for use (i.e. I don't want to allow old or weak algorithms).
What I want to know; which order are the algorithms negotiated?

I know the client and the server have to agree on which algorithm to use. But does the list need to be ordered from most preferred -> least preferred? Or The other way around?  The lists in the man page appear to be ordered first by algorithm group, with preferred groups first, but within each group, the algorithms seem to be ordered from least preferred to most.

Basically, my question boils down to, will the client and server negotiate the "strongest" algorithm they both support (where "strongest" is defined internally to OpenSSH), or will it pick the first/latest algorithm in both (server and client) supported algorithms lists?

How can I tell which algorithms are negotiated for a given connection?  I have run ssh with -v -v -v and I see a lot of spew from kex_parse_kexinit. But I can't tell which algorithm is settled upon from that spew.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see more precise details of how the various algorithms are negotiated in [RFC 4253, Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1), but basically:

- The algorithms in `ssh_config` (or the user's `~/.ssh/config`) and in `sshd_config` are ranked by preference, highest to lowest.
- The server chooses the first algorithm on the client's list that it also supports. Hence, the choice is biased towards the client's preferences.

The Cipher and MAC algorithms do show up in verbose output, e.g.

```
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
```

Last I checked, OpenSSH does not say what exact Kex algorithm it chooses though. Maybe this will change in the future.